# Running xen inside VirtualBox, possible?

Tags: virtualbox, xen

Can i run a Linux system inside VirtualBox or VMware , with xen kernel ?
It's not intended for a real server or production workplace , just to learn the configuration of XEN.

BTW: target computer supports Intel VT feature

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible. But you won't be able to run xen hvm domains (because it requires hardware virtualization, that is not available inside of virtual machine). Only PV domains.

Comment: be sure to use "clocksource=pit" to boot (at least for Linux 3.0+ kernels). VirtualBox and/or VMware might have the ability to passthrough the VT-x features to a guest, which would allow nested HVM guests.

Comment: how do you set clocksource=pit ?